# What is the color of Venus if it has no atmosphere?

Tags: venus, surface

Mars looks reddish and Mercury looks gray because they lack thick atmospheres and we can see their "real color" easily, how about Venus? Is the surface of Venus really yellowish in color?

Comment: I found this:  http://www.universetoday.com/46436/what-color-is-venus/ "The surface of the planet is littered with brownish-red volcanic rocks. The bright red color you see in the Soviet Venera images of Venus have been brightened to show more surface detail."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the webpage from the Planetary Habitability Laboratory of the University of Puerto Rico: [The Real Colors of Venus without the Clouds](http://phl.upr.edu/library/media/therealcolorsofvenuswithouttheclouds), did the following:

> We combined radar topography and emissivity to generate the surface texture assuming a generalized basalt composition with gray to light brown tones, depending on the iron and sulfur content. In the images we also included the effect of the 'orange sky' of Venus thus given its surface a more dark brown appearance

As in the image below. 
Additionally, according to the model the scientists made, they state that

> Under white light the surface should look grayish and more similar to the Moon.

[image]

*As an aside, the website also shows a fictional map of Venus with 70% surface water.*